# Installing outlet near toilet

Tags: electrical, toilet, gfci

In the middle of a bathroom remodel and I have the walls gutted.  I'm considering installing an outlet on the far side of the bathroom which will be near a toilet.

There's an existing GFCI outlet near the sink area.  I'd like to run a line from the load of that GFCI to the new outlet.

Do I need to have a second GFCI because it'll be within a couple feet of the toilet?  Or is just being on the load acceptable?

Comment: If you're connecting to the load side of the existing GFCI, then your new outlet will be protected by the old GFCI. You don't need to install a new GFCI outlet there.

Comment: I guess I have a follow up question then.  I just noticed both loads on the GFCI are full.  One runs to a switch for the bathroom lights, and one for the lights in my living room on the other side of the wall for some reason.  I can get to all of the wiring. Can I branch off with a jbox from the living room load?

Comment: It's odd that your lights are being GFCI protected (not really a problem - just odd). Could you move one or both of those to the Line side of the GFCI to free up a Load connection?

Comment: I think the previous home owners might have done it for ease of access.  They ran from the panel to the bathroom and just took the easy way of running through the GFCI instead of running a second circuit to the living room.

Comment: If you're in the US, the circuit supplying the GFCI receptacle in the bathroom, should be 20 amperes and not supply anything outside of the bathroom.  If you want GFCI protection, simply connect the required branches to the LOAD side of the GFCI. If you have too many branches, you can use pigtails (you should use pigtails for anything more than a single branch, in my opinion).  Lastly, it sounds like the box might be beyond the box fill limit.

Comment: Ok, I'll revisit the additional outlet later after I've had a chance to reroute the living room circuit. I had a feeling...ty both for your feedback.

Comment: @brhans Sounds like an answer

Answer (score 2):

GFCIs are actually designed to do this sort of thing. That's what the LOAD part of your GFCI is for. When anything happens on that side, that would trip it if it were a GFCI, the GFCI triggers. So any outlets on that side of the circuit are considered to be GFCI protected.

[image]

I would highly recommend you buy a circuit tester that has a GFCI trip switch

[image]

Pressing the button feeds the hot through the ground, which should trip the GFCI.

Comment: When a ground fault occurs on the load side, the GFCI triggers. GFCI are not overcurrent protection devices.